# Error AndroidX dependencies when i use Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am following I youtube tutorial to create an android app at android studio. I am going fine but when I change my build.gradle files I get this error:

> "Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException:
> Configuration :app:debugRuntimeClasspath contains AndroidX
> dependencies, but the android.useAndroidX property is not enabled,
> which may cause runtime issues. "

Here my github for the project :https://github.com/fanhsg-lab/Duolingo.git

The last change is what cause the error.

And I cant fix it by adding:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Because this creates more errors in my MainActivity cause I use Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You are using support libraries that are not compatible with **AndroidX**, like: `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`.

To migrate your project, you need to:

1. Append this to `gradle.properties` to enable AndroidX migration:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

2. Replace legacy support libraries with AndroidX ones, for ex:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Will be replaced with:

```java
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
```

3. Replace all legacy support classes references with AndroidX ones, for ex:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Will be replaced with:

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Comment: i tried this solution but when i add android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true I get a lot of erros i my MainActivity. When i run this is what i get 7 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

  1.  Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs   2.  Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs. ....

Comment: Does the Youtuber use previous technology than i do and i get this problems?

Comment: Yes, you need to set SDK version to 33. Errors in MainActivity need to be resolved as mentioned in point 3.